# google apps script - trying to create button that pastes a model template (160 rows, 4 columns) each time i press it. w/ formatting, formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

i've created and formatted a basic model, with data validation, formulas and visual formatting. that model is 4 columns, 160 rows with some of the cells being merged.

I'm wondering if i can create a button on my sheet with google apps script that takes the source template with everything included and pastes it at the beginning of my sheet, moving everything else to the right (this may mean autocreating columns). I will be doing this each time a new project arises, and want to see most recent at the beginning. alternatively, if i need to add new columns manually before pasting that works too - but what's important is that merged cells and formulas paste over

I tried stringing together a number of scripts i found on different forums online but cannot even get to the specifying range and determining a place of output, let alone the formulas and auto-creating columns. any help is much appreciated!please let me know if i can clarify anything here

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to copy 4 columns ahead of the first column.

First, I insert 4 columns start at A which shifts A to E.  Next I copy the range E to H to A to D.  This will automatically adjust formulas for the change in columns.  Lastly, I overwrite the contents of A to D with only the formulas.  All values in those columns will be 0.

```
function test() {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Test");
    let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    sheet.insertColumns(1,4);
    let range = sheet.getRange(1,5,lastRow,4);
    range.copyTo(sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,4));
    range = sheet.getRange(2,1,lastRow-1,4); //  Dont overwrite header
    range.setFormulas(range.getFormulas());
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log("Error in test: "+err)
  }
}
```

Reference

- [Sheet.insertColumns()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertColumns(Integer,Integer))
- [Range.copyTo()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))
- [Range.getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFormulas())
- [Range.setFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulas(String))